# Вопрос по Django. Как определить id текущей категории и отобразить товары относящиеся к данной категории

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как определить id категории, чтобы использовать его для отображения статей относящихся к данной категории.
[Django]
Класс во views:

```
class CategoryDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'category_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'category_list'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)        
        context['posts_cat'] = Post.objects.filter(title='Статья 1') # заглушка для теста
        return context
```

В urls страница доступна по адресу:
path('category/int:pk', CategoryDetail.as_view(), name='category_list'),

Файл models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dateCreation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    postCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='PostCategory')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    text = models.TextField()


class PostCategory(models.Model):
    postThrough = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoryThrough = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Как определить id текущей категории и добраться от класса Post до Category, при условии, что связь идет через класс PostCaategory?

Для отображения товаров из данной категории построил цепочку, но джанго выдает ошибку.
Post.objects.filter(postCategory=PostCategory.objects.filter(              categoryThrough=Category.objects.filter(id=pk)))

Comment: `Post.objects.filter(postCategory__id=pk)` вроде так должно работать

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!
id категории определил через kwargs
Post.objects.filter(postCategory__id=self.kwargs['pk'])